# R: Merge different size dataframes by column

Tags: r, merge

I am currently trying to merge two dataframes that share a column in R. It shouldn't be a problem,  but I kepp getting a strange error when using merge. 
(This is test data, the tables are imported with read.csv2 from csv)

Dataframe 1:

```
match                              similar
aa.alcoholics_anonymous.n.01       mission.n.01
aa.associate_in_arts.n.01          associate_in_nursing.n.01
abbreviation.abbreviation.n.01     word.n.01  
abbreviation.abbreviation.n.02     truncation.n.03
aberration.aberrance.n.01          varix.n.01
aberration.aberration.n.02         dissociative_disorder.n.01
aberration.aberration.n.03         tyndall_effect.n.01 
abnormality.abnormality.n.01       varix.n.01
abnormality.abnormality.n.02       imbecility.n.01
abnormality.abnormality.n.03       unusualness.n.01
```

Dataframe 2:

```
match                            wordnet_number
aa.alcoholics_anonymous.n.01     2
aa.associate_in_arts.n.01        3
abbreviation.abbreviation.n.01   1
aberration.aberrance.n.01        1
aberration.aberration.n.02       2
aberration.aberration.n.03       3
abnormality.abnormality.n.01     1
```

The desired result should look like this:

```
match                            similar                   Wordnet_number
aa.alcoholics_anonymous.n.01     mission.n.01               2
aa.associate_in_arts.n.01        associate_in_nursing.n.01  3
abbreviation.abbreviation.n.01   word.n.01                  2
abbreviation.abbreviation.n.02   truncation.n.03            NA
aberration.aberrance.n.01        varix.n.01                 1
aberration.aberration.n.02       dissociative_disorder.n.01 2
aberration.aberration.n.03       tyndall_effect.n.01        3
abnormality.abnormality.n.01     varix.n.01                 1
abnormality.abnormality.n.02     imbecility.n.01            NA
abnormality.abnormality.n.03     unusualness.n.01           NA
```

Normally, merge  by column "match" should work fine? (done similar before), but for some reason, I keep getting this result:

total <- merge(test1, test2, by ="match", all = TRUE)

```
match                           similar                   wordnet_number
aa.alcoholics_anonymous.n.01    mission.n.01              NA
aa.associate_in_arts.n.01       associate_in_nursing.n.01 NA
abbreviation.abbreviation.n.01  word.n.01                 NA
abbreviation.abbreviation.n.02  truncation.n.03           NA
aberration.aberrance.n.01       varix.n.01                NA
aberration.aberration.n.02     dissociative_disorder.n.01 NA
aberration.aberration.n.03      tyndall_effect.n.01       NA
abnormality.abnormality.n.01    varix.n.01                NA
abnormality.abnormality.n.02    imbecility.n.01           NA
abnormality.abnormality.n.03    unusualness.n.01          NA
aa.alcoholics_anonymous.n.01    NA                         2
aa.associate_in_arts.n.01       NA                         3
abbreviation.abbreviation.n.01  NA                         1
aberration.aberrance.n.01       NA                         1
aberration.aberration.n.02      NA                         2
aberration.aberration.n.03      NA                         3
abnormality.abnormality.n.01    NA                         1
```

Probably a stupid error, but how do I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `print` on those "match" columns. I bet one of them has trailing spaces. Or post the output of `dput(dataframe1)` and `dput(dataframe2)` rather than the print.data.frame output

Answer (score 0):

According to `help(merge)`, you should use `incomparables = NA` when merging data frames on only one column. Looks like it does the trick here.

```
merge(test1, test2, by = "match", all = TRUE, incomparables = NA)
#                             match                    similar wordnet_number
# 1    aa.alcoholics_anonymous.n.01               mission.n.01              2
# 2       aa.associate_in_arts.n.01  associate_in_nursing.n.01              3
# 3  abbreviation.abbreviation.n.01                  word.n.01              1
# 4  abbreviation.abbreviation.n.02            truncation.n.03             NA
# 5       aberration.aberrance.n.01                 varix.n.01              1
# 6      aberration.aberration.n.02 dissociative_disorder.n.01              2
# 7      aberration.aberration.n.03        tyndall_effect.n.01              3
# 8    abnormality.abnormality.n.01                 varix.n.01              1
# 9    abnormality.abnormality.n.02            imbecility.n.01             NA
# 10   abnormality.abnormality.n.03           unusualness.n.01             NA
```